# Getting error while using ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have the following code in my angular controller

(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app.mp')
        .controller('mp', mp);

```
function mp(dataservice, logger, $scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.apiRequest = {
        unitId: 68105,
        employeeId: 123
    };

    getEarnings(vm.apiRequest);

    $scope.myData = '';

    $scope.EmployeeGridOptions = {
        data: 'EmployeeData'
    };


    function getEarnings(request) {
        return dataservice.getEarnings(request).then(function (data) {
            $scope.EmployeeData = data;

            //$scope.EmployeeRowCount = data.TotalRowCount;
            //vm.Earnings = data;
            //vm.ptoEarningsCount = data.length;
            // return data;
        }).catch(function (err) {
            logger.error('Managing Partner view activation failed: ' + err);
        });
    }
}
```

})();

and following in my angular web page

```
<div ng-controller="mp as vm">
    <div id="grid1" ng-grid="gridOptions" class="gridStyle"></div>
</div>
```

I have been getting the following error and grid does not display records..I have researched a lot over web but I could not get any resolution.

My promise returns results which are binded to EmployeeData.

Following is the error: Unable to set property 'gridDim' of undefined or null reference [object Object]

Any help with this is highly appreciated

Comment: You're not using EmployeeGridOptions anywhere, do you?

Comment: Sorry..Grid options was replcaed with EmployeeGridOptions..I did not paste the updated code

Comment: Does your getEarnings function return the requiered data as result? Wouldn't you want to use a property of the response such as data or anything else?

Comment: I just noticed your question wasn't formatted correctly, so... Are you using closures???? What's the purpose for you doing it so?

Comment: Yes I confirmed data is returned properly from service layer. Its data binding issue..I am able to move further and its now just the data is getting overlapped when I bind the whole result set to grid